# Creating new files with using Os module

Tags: python, web-scraping, anaconda, python-3.6

## Somebody who knows the solution

```
import os
```

Using this piece of code to create a file this method wil be used inside of a while loop

```
def get_data(self,url):
            pagina = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
            data = BeautifulSoup(pagina, "html.parser")
            dest = "C:\\Users\\Dennis.Pieruschka\\Documents\\Scraper\\Links"
            html = ".html"
            brackets = "\\"
            string = dest + brackets + url + html
            with open(string, 'w') as f:
                f.write(data)
                f.close()
   
    Somehow i cant parse in the name of the URL and use it to name                        the file 
Somebody knows how to fix it i get this error 

    OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Dennis.Pieruschka\\Documents\\Scraper\\Links\\http://www.visservanbaars.nl/vacatures/senior-oracle-dba-osb-weblogic/.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have : or \ or / on a file name in Windows

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot have : in a filename and / will be interpreted as a directory separator.
You could do something like

```
encoded_url = url[5:] #remove 'http:
encoded_url = encoded_url.replace('/','-' # replace / with -
```

However, a better solution would be to encode all special characters
    import urllib.parse
    encoded_url = urllib.parse.quote(url)